# Salt-cloud rackspace configuration that works

Tags: ubuntu, salt-stack, rackspace-cloud, rackspace, salt-cloud

I use saltstack from configuration management and want to utilize salt-cloud to provision and automate our environments.  The issue is that most the documentation seems terribly outdated.  We have built configurations using these guides but to no avail:

- https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/clouds/all/salt.cloud.clouds.openstack.html

This guide ends giving us the error that the openstack driver is deprecated and we need to use Nova. Attepting to use Nova downgrades us to python 2.7 and it can't find the python-novaclient module, even though it is installed

- https://www.unixhot.com/docs/saltstack/topics/cloud/rackspace.html

This guide ends in similar issues.

Really, I am interested in connecting with someone who is using an up-to-date server OS (we use Ubuntu 18) that uses salt-cloud and Rackspace.  I would love to pick your brain about configuration. I'm sorry if this is poorly organized. First time poster.

Thanks